# Avoiding Task.Run causing deadlock on Main thread (C#)

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, threadpool

I believe, while unlikely, that it is possible for a Task queued up using `Task.Run()` to end up running on the Main thread.

I'm concerned that (in my WPF app), If I am using `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()`, or similar, inside this Task, I will cause a deadlock.

Is this a valid fear? If so, is there a way to prevent this from happening (without checking the current thread *isnt* the main thread).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe, while unlikely, that it is possible for a Task queued up using Task.Run() to end up running on the Main thread.

You believe incorrectly: this is not possible. `Task.Run` dispatches to the ThreadPool, not the UI thread's dispatcher. The two are entirely separate.

> I'm concerned that (in my WPF app), If I am using App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(), or similar, inside this Task, I will cause a deadlock.

You should avoid using `Invoke` anyway, because of the risk of deadlocks. The risk is that the UI thread is waiting for your thread to do something, and by synchronously waiting for the UI thread to be free enough to process your message, you're risking deadlock.

You can normally use `BeginInvoke` instead (having a background thread whose progress depends on what the UI is doing is normally bad design), but you rarely need this when you're using `await` and `Progress<T>`/`IProgress<T>`.

Comment: I've noticed using `Parallel.ForEach` from the TPL will often run a thread on the 'Main' thread. Yes, this call blocks the calling thread, so it makes sense to utilize this 'spare' thread. 
Is this some TPL 'magic'? As MSDN states it gets it's allocation from the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` will use the thread it's called on, plus any number of additional threads as needed. If you call it from the UI thread, yes it will use the UI thread. If you call it from a non-UI thread, it won't use the UI thread.